# too much .js, and .css files are generated in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, frontend

I'm using nextjs and Typescript. I implemented my web app but in production mode, I see too many .js, and .css files are loaded and this process occurs in sequential not parallel. I think nextjs should generate all of this process in one webpack file but it doesn't happen. What should I do? Any idea for fonts, images, js files, and .css files? Another point I should say. I'm using SCSS files that against the instruction mentioned in the Nextjs doc, are placed in the components folder and its subfolders instead of the styles folder.

```js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

// next.js configuration
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['ibexcdn.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      nextTranslate,
      {
        webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
          return config;
        },
      },
    ],
    withBundleAnalyzer,

    [
      withPWA,
      {
        pwa: {
          disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
          dest: 'public',
          runtimeCaching: [
            {
              urlPattern: /.(?:eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|font.css)$/i,
              handler: 'NetworkFirst',
              options: {
                cacheName: 'static-font-assets',
                expiration: {
                  maxEntries: 4,
                  maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 7 days
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },

      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Shouldn't only one file make it huge payload. Check code-splitting config in ur code or docs

Comment: @Sagar but as you can see in the attached images, too many CSS files that are not relevant to the home page are loaded and some of the relevant CSS files have a very low size that is loaded in a sequential manner. Another point I should say. I'm using SCSS files that against the instruction mentioned in the Nextjs doc, are placed in the components folder and its sub folders instead of the styles folder.

Comment: Check ur webpack settings and how you import comps maybe that might help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added a lot of imports to your components, create an empty page with 1 API request and see the resources and scripts loaded.

After, try to add one-by-one components and see what happends.

It's the only proper way to check what happens

Also, `delete libs` you are not using for your project, check your `package.json` file of your project.

Comment: thanks, @illia chill. I updated my question. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: I did all your advice but still doesn't work. I created one page with just one API and without any import but still, there are a lot of js, css, and font files